# Best way to move DB file from external storage to internal

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to move my DB file which is stored in external storage to internal storage before/while doing app upgrade. Can anyone please suggest best approach to do so.

```
public static final String INTERNAL_DATABASE_FILE_PATH = "data/data/project_pkg_name/databases/";
    public static final String EXTERN_DATABASE_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
if (PermissionUtil.isExternalPermissionGranted()) {
try {
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getExternalDbPath());

           String directoryName = "/databases"; // Replace with your directory name
           File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParentFile(), directoryName);

           if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs()
           }
           File fileOut = new File(INTERNAL_DATABASE_FILE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME);
           if(!fileOut.exists()) {
               fileOut.createNewFile();
           }
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOut, false);
           fos.getChannel().transferFrom(fis.getChannel(), 0, fis.getChannel().size());
           // or fis.getChannel().transferTo(0, fis.getChannel().size(), fos.getChannel());
           fis.close();
           fos.close();
       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());
       }
    }
```

I m trying above code but here createFile throws No such file or directory error. I already have following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_*"/>
```

Comment: external path :-  /storage/emulated/0/xyz.db
internal path should be  : - data/data/PROJECT_PKG_NAME/databases/xyz.db

Comment: `if(!fileOut.exists()) {
               fileOut.createNewFile();
           }` Better remove that code. The new FileOutputStream() will create the file.

Comment: FileOutPutStream was throwing some access denied error

Comment: Who put that file there on external storage? Also use file.exists() and file.canRead() before you try to copy the file.

Comment: `"data/data/project_pkg_name/databases/"` That should be: "/data/data/project_pkg_name/databases/"